# Streaming video through wifi routers

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

Let's say that I live in a large villa where all of it is covered with a WiFi network. I have a small drone with a camera mounted on it, and I want to stream the video captured by the camera on the drone through the WiFi routers to my laptop, which is connected to the same WiFi network. I'll then process the video in Maltab.

Now to the networking part (I'm a beginner in this field):

1- Generally speaking, is this type of networking considered peer-to-peer networking? Please note that i want the data to pass through the WiFi routers, not get uploaded and downloaded online (My understanding that this thing is possible and that's how some applications like AirDroid work, not quite sure of that though)

2- If that exists, any hint on how to calculate the possible bandwidth of this type of connections?

3- Any ideas on how to implement that? for example, if i connect the camera to a raspberry pi and install some server software on it and assign it to an IP address. would connecting to that IP address be implicitly done through my router (given i do some certain needed settings)? If not, then how to do this?

Any keywords or articles that will help me do more search on this topic are very appreciated.

And you can see that i almost have no knowledge in this area. Any book or online course suggestions regarding this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will address each of your bullets. There is an easier way and a slightly harder way to do all of this. The easier way would be if the drone you had already had built in wireless capability. I am assuming that is not the case because you are asking about having a camera, hooking it up to a pi, and then hosting it from there to connect to. Either way, it's all possible.

1. Yes, it will be peer to peer. The camera will hooked to the pi (unless it already has wireless, then no pi is needed). VLC will be used on the pi to "host" the camera stream to connect to on your laptop. No internet involved.
2. The bandwidth calculation will be based on framerate and resolution. There are a few bandwidth calculators out there. My favorite is the [AXIS Design Tool](http://www.axis.com/us/en/tools/axis-design-tool) The bandwidth can be further defined in the vlc server string used when setting up the hosting stream URL.
3. Hook camera to drone. Hook drone to pi. Have a power source that can run everything. Install Raspian or another light distro of your choice. Connect pi to network. Run `ifconfig` to grab IP. Run this command in VLC to setup the server `cvlc -vvv v4l2:///dev/video0 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=mp2v,vb=800,acodec=none}:rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/}'` . This command tells the pi "Hey, my webcam is installed locally at /dev/video0. I want to transcode it to mp2v, use a bitrate of 800 kbps and have no audio codec. I also want the rtsp port to be 8554."
   Now, start VLC on your laptop. File > Open Network Stream > "rtsp://ip_address_of_pi:8554". You should now get the live stream and can record or do whatever from there.

For further research, you can search for hosting rtsp streams with VLC or unicast rtp streaming.

Comment: If i want to read the video using Matlab, i do need to set up a TCP/IP client in Matlab to grab the data right?

Comment: @OmarHommos not really sure about the programming side. I will look into it and let you know if i can find anything. But i'd search for pulling rtsp stream into matlab.

Comment: I just remembered that Matlab can acquire images from an IP camera once an IP is specified. Details are in this link: http://www.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/ipcamera/ug/ipcam.html
Many thanks!